# is it possible to hide file on external storage?

Tags: java, android, file, encryption, android-external-storage

I want to hide my pdf file, I tried encrypting file but I got out of memory error because file is too big.I try add "." front of file name like that ".pdfs/" but it doesn't work.
is there any solution this case?

I use download manager library [here](https://github.com/yxl/DownloadProvider), It is prevent to download internal storage, I have to use external storage

Comment: Instead of putting it on external storage, put it on internal storage. Then, you do not need to waste time attempting to hide it (which, technically speaking, is not possible).

Comment: How big is your file? It would have to be absolutely gigantic if you're getting an outofmemory error

Comment: 250mb+ @mstorkson

Comment: @CommonsWare I use download manager library, It is prevent to download internel storage, I have to use external storage

Comment: "I use download manager library" -- if you mean `DownloadManager`, perhaps stop using that, and download the content yourself using an HTTP client API and an `IntentService`. Ideally, `DownloadManager` would provide ways for you to use `FileProvider`, allowing you to direct the download to internal storage, but unfortunately [that is not an option](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221670).

Comment: I mean this library https://github.com/yxl/DownloadProvider

Answer (score 2):

> I tried encrypting file but I got out of memory error because file is too big

Then instead of reading whole file and encrypting such huge block of data, read it in smaller portions, encrypt these portions, save it and then read another portion for encryption. Repeat until done.

> I use download manager library, It is prevent to download internel storage, I have to use external storage

But you do not have to use `Download Manager` so once you fetch the file yourself, you can store it whenever you want incl. your own private storage of your choice.

Comment: I use https://github.com/yxl/DownloadProvider this library this, it cover all my need  and It is too hard to change. But I will try ecrypting smaller portions.